# How to tell my linter to flag require() statements with a warning

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, visual-studio-code, eslint

I've set up a new nodeJS project with typescript. My linter is flagging me with errors, for example:

```js
import authentication from "./routes/authentication"; // Flags "Cannot find module ..."
```

I would like it to flag a warning/error for these statements, as they break my app when I try to load it:

```js
const pool = require("../database/db"); // Currently not flagging as a warning either for the fact that the file does not exist, or that it is using a require() statement.
```

I'm guessing `eslint` is doing my linting. But I haven't explicitly set it up. I tried creating and playing with a `.eslint.rc` file, but nothing happened.

1. How do I check what my linter is? I can't find anything in my VS-Code settings to say what I'm using. I can't find any reference to it in my `package.json` or `tsconfig.json` files that reference a linter either?
2. How do I then get my linter to flag `require()` statements?

---

So it looks like `eslint` was already running. It was installed in my extensions, but I've no idea what rules it was using. It must have been some defaults?

I ran  `yarn add eslint -D` and `npx eslint --init` to set up `eslint`. Then I changed the `rules:` object in my `.eslintrc.js` file. This seems to have changed the linting, which suggests I was already using `eslint`.

I haven't yet worked out how to flag errors for the `require()` statements. I've found [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/mK54Cn4ceac?t=1126), which explains that:

- `require()` statements are just functions. We can write `require()` statements within `if()` conditions and functions. This is not possible with `import ... from ...` statements
- Because `require()` statements are functions, they are only being called in runtime. `import`s are static, so they are being checked by typescript in parse time. This is useful as it means we can get errors before moving into runtime.

Comment: If you are using eslint or tslint there is a rule for that called `no-require-imports` [see link](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-require-imports.md). If using eslint you'll have to install the typescript-eslint package first though.

Comment: OK, so if I run ```yarn add typescript-eslint -D``` and then add ```'no-var-requires': 1,``` to my ```.eslint``` files under ```rules: {}``` then it should work? Only it's not had any effect when I just tried it?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I've fixed it. I didn't want to install ```typescript-eslint```. It worked when I followed these instructions: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md. For some reason my linting wasn't picking some items up until I ran this command: ```yarn eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I never found a better way of checking what linter my VS-Code was running other than setting up `eslint` with the  [github.com/typescript-eslint/...](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md) instructions and then playing with the `.eslintrc.js` file to see that the rules changed. Even then I had to run`yarn eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx` before the `rules:{}` in my `.eslintrc.js` started to take effect.
2. In order to get the `require()` statements to flag up with my linter, I added the following to my `.eslintrc.js` `rules:{}` property:

```json
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 1,
    ...
  }
```

Although this didn't take effect until after I'd followed the steps described in item 1. As stated above, for some reason I had to run `yarn eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx` before the `rules:{}` in my `.eslintrc.js` started to take effect.